# the free product of two presentations is isomorphic to a third presentation using UP of free product.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, universal-property, free-product, coproduct

Here is the question that I want an answer to it using commutative diagrams (as small number of them as possible):

Prove that the free product of $ \langle g_1, \dots ,g_m | r_1, \dots ,r_n \rangle$ and $ \langle h_1, \dots ,h_k| s_1, \dots ,s_l \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\langle g_1, \dots ,g_m,h_1, \dots ,h_k|r_1, \dots ,r_n,s_1, \dots ,s_l \rangle.$

I had an incomplete proof for it where I ignored the relations, which is off course a mistake. I showed that the free group of a disjoint union $F(A\amalg B)$ is isomorphic to the free product of the corresponding free groups $F(A)*F(B)$.

Now, my question is:

How can I prove this problem using the Universal property of free product?

The Universal property of free product is:

Note that the free product is the "coproduct in the category of groups." The universal property is:

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two groups,then for any group $G$ and for any pair of homomorphisms $\varphi_1:G_1 \to G$ and $\varphi_2:G_2 \to G$ there is a unique homomorphism $G_1 * G_2$ that on words representatives' of length one agrees with $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2.$

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please specify (in the post) which definition of $\langle g_1, \dots ,g_m\mid r_1, \dots ,r_n \rangle$ you want to use? There are several (equivalent).

Comment: The correct formulation of the universal property for the free product is: $G_1*G_2$ comes with two homomorphisms $\psi_i:G_i\to G_1*G_2$, and the triple $(G_1*G_2,\psi_1,\psi_2)$ is characterized (up to isomorphism) by:  for any pair of homomorphisms $\varphi_1:G_1 \to G$ and $\varphi_2:G_2 \to G$ there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi:G_1 * G_2\to G$ such that $\varphi\circ\psi_i=\varphi_i$. There is no categorical notion of `words representatives of length one'.

Comment: ok, thank you, but then how can I proof the required using the correct universal property you mentioned?@AnneBauval

Comment: I am trying to think about it, but again: please specify (in the post) which definition of $\langle g_1, \dots ,g_m\mid r_1, \dots ,r_n \rangle$
 you want to use (and correct the universal property of the free product).

Comment: Sure will do ! Thanks

Comment: I am typing an answer, choosing the definition of $ \langle g_1, \dots ,g_m\mid r_1, \dots ,r_n \rangle$ by universal property. I hope you agree with that choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to use a different definition of presentation: A group $G$ with presentation $\langle S| R \rangle$ is the quotient $F/N(R)$ where $F$ is the free group generated on $S$ and $N(R)$ is the smallest normal subgroup generated by $R$.

Now for $\langle F(S_i) \mid N(R_i)\rangle:=G_i$ you want to figure out their coproduct.

Here's a sketch of how I think the argument should go. No promises, but the flavor is probably something similar.

Well note that there are maps $F(S_i) \to (F(S_1 \cup S_2)/N(R_1 \cup R_2):=H)$ induced by just sending $S_i \to S_i$ and since $N(R_i)$ is killed in the image, we get induced maps $G_i \to H$ so by the universal property of coproducts a unique map $G_1*G_2 \to H$. First show that this map is surjective and $N(R_1 \cup R_2)$ is contained in the kernel. Then use uniqueness to deduce that it's exactly the kernel

---

since you tagged this algebraic topology:

Let $G_i$ have presentation complex given by the wedge of $S_i$ circles with a two cell glued in for each element of $R_i$. Then the coproduct in pointed spaces is the wedge sum and use Van Kampen's theorem (Pushouts are sent to pushouts in good circumstances) to deduce the result.

Comment: Can you please add some more details? It is not a HW problem.

Comment: uhhh... what details sorry i wasn't withholding information. I was just answering off the top of the dome

Comment: I mean you said "a sketch" right? So some details are missing, right?

Comment: For example you said, "First show that this map is surjective and $N(S_1 \cup S_2)$ is contained in the kernel. Then use uniqueness to deduce that it's exactly the kernel" right?

Comment: sure what part of that is confusing?

Comment: if you can please show me all the details of the statement I stated in my previous comment I would greatly appreciate this.

Comment: surjectivity follows from checking on generators. For being contained in the kernel, it follows from the universal property of pushouts it follows that that the kernel contains the normal subgroups generated by the image of $N(R_1)$ and $N(R_2)$ in $F(S_1 \cup S_2)$ and in particular the image of $R_1$ and $R_2$, hence the normal subgroup they generate as claimed. For uniqueness, you can either argue by hand at this point or try the third isomorphism theorem to cook up another homomorphism making this diagram commute with bigger kernel, contradicting uniqueness

Answer (score 1):

The two (not necessarily finitely) presented groups $G_i:=\langle S_i\mid R_i\rangle$ ($i=1,2$) come with maps $\sigma_i:S_i\to G_i$, and $(G_i,\sigma_i)$ is characterized (up to isomorphism) by the following universal property:

- $\sigma_i^*(R_i)=1$, i.e. $\forall s_1^{n_1}\dots s_j^{n_j}\in R_i\quad\sigma_i(s_1)^{n_1}\dots\sigma_i(s_j)^{n_j}$ is the identity element of $G_i$;
- for every group $H$ and every map $f:S_i\to H$ such that $f^*(R_i)=1$, there is a unique homomorphism $F:G_i\to H$ such that $F\circ\sigma_i=f$.

The free product $G_0:=G_1*G_2$ comes with two homomorphisms $\psi_i:G_i\to G_0$  ($i=1,2$), and $(G_0,\psi_1,\psi_2)$ is characterized (up to isomorphism) by the following universal property (correcting your formulation, since there is no categorical notion of `words representatives of length one'):

- for any group $G$ and any pair of homomorphisms $\phi_i:G_i\to G$ ($i=1,2$), there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi:G_0→G$ such that $\varphi∘ψ_i=\varphi_i$  ($i=1,2$).

Let $S:=S_1\sqcup S_2$ and $R:=R_1\sqcup R_2$. In order to prove that $G_0$ is isomorphic to $\langle S\mid R\rangle$, it will suffice to define a map $\sigma:S\to G_0$ such that:

- $\sigma^*(R)=1$
- for every group $H$ and every map $f:S\to H$ such that $f^*(R)=1$, there is a unique homomorphism $F:G_0\to H$ such that $F\circ\sigma=f$.

First define $\sigma:=(\psi_1\circ\sigma_1)\sqcup(\psi_2\circ\sigma_2).$

- The first property is easy to check: for every $r\in R_i$ ($i=1,2$), $\sigma^*(r)=(\psi_i\circ\sigma_i)^*(r)=\psi_i(\sigma_i^*(r))=\psi_i(1_{G_i})=1_{G_0}$.
- Let now $H$ be a group and $f:S\to H$ be a map such that $f^*(R)=1$.

  - For $i=1,2$, the map $f_i:=f_{|S_i}:S_i\to H$ satisfies $f_i^*(R_i)=1$ hence there is a (unique) homomorphism $\varphi_i:G_i\to H$ such that $\varphi_i\circ\sigma_i=f_i$. Then, there is a (unique) homomorphism $\varphi:G_0\to H$ such that $\varphi_i=\varphi\circ\psi_i$ ($i=1,2$). Such a $\varphi$ satisfies $$\varphi\circ\sigma=(\varphi\circ\psi_1\circ\sigma_1)\sqcup(\varphi\circ\psi_2\circ\sigma_2)=(\varphi_1\circ\sigma_1)\sqcup(\varphi_2\circ\sigma_2)=f_1\sqcup f_2=f.$$
  - Any other homomorphism $F:G_0\to H$ such that $F\circ\sigma=f$ is equal to $\varphi$, since $F\circ\psi_i\circ\sigma_i=f_i=\varphi_i\circ\sigma_i$ ($i=1,2$) $\implies F\circ\psi_i=\varphi_i=\varphi\circ\psi_i$ ($i=1,2$) $\implies F=\varphi$.

Comment: why $f^*(R) = 1$?

Comment: can we do the proof using commutative diagrams then?

Comment: "Why $f^*(R) = 1$?": ?? these are the $f$'s for which something must be satisfied, in the definition of a group presentation by universal property.

Comment: You can illustrate my proof with some diagrams if you like. I won't.